# Topologic graph algorithm with queue structure does not return the right order

Tags: c

After a few hours of trying to debug this, I'm coming here looking for kind souls who'd happen to be willing to dive into my issue. I'm making a program that returns/prints the topological order of a graph, but it won't print the right order. I might have an issue when deleting nodes from the predecessors list.

My graph has 6 nodes (0 to 5) and 5 arcs as follows:

```
5 -> 1
5 -> 0
3 -> 5
4 -> 3
2 -> 3
```

And I get by initializing the graph the following successors and predecessors queues:

```
Successors of 0: EMPTY
Successors of 1: EMPTY
Successors of 2: 3
Successors of 3: 5
Successors of 4: 3
Successors of 5: 1 0
Predecessors of 0: 5
Predecessors of 1: 5
Predecessors of 2: EMPTY
Predecessors of 3: 4 2
Predecessors of 4: EMPTY
Predecessors of 5: 3
```

These are initialized by the loadingGraph() function (which works fine since it returns the right result without issue).

Here's the graph structure I am using. I do malloc and all accordingly, of course.

```
typedef struct {
   int content;
   struct cell* next;
} cell;

typedef struct {
   cell* start;
   cell* end;
} queue;

typedef struct {
   int numberNode;
   int numberArc;

   queue *successors;
   queue *predecessors;

} graph;
```

And this is the main program:

```
int main() {
    int i, j, k;
    int loopTime = 0;

    queue *nodeTopologicalOrder = malloc(sizeof (queue));
    graph *g = malloc(sizeof (graph));
    int *done = calloc(g->numberNode, sizeof (int));

    loadingGraph(g);

    while (loopTime < 2) {

        for (i = 0; i < g->numberNode; i++) {
            // If the node i does not have predecessors then
            if (((g->predecessors[i]).start == NULL) && (done[i] == 0)) {
                //  It is deleted from the graph and from the nodes having i as predecessor in their predecessors queues
                for (j = 0; j < g->numberNode; j++) {         
                    deleteElement(&(g->predecessors[j]), i);
                }

                // The node i is added to the topological queue and won't be re-processed.
                done[i] = 1;
                add(i, nodeTopologicalOrder);
            }
        }
        loopTime++;    
    }
    printf("\nTopological Order :");
    display(*nodeTopologicalOrder);

    return 0;
}
```

Nevertheless, I get the following result, which is erroned (should be 2 4 3 5 0 1):

```
Topological Order :2 3 4 5 0 1
```

It seems my issue is in my deleteElement() function but when I test it, it is just fine! It deletes the element if there's a matching one in the queue, else it returns the queue as it is. But when I use it in the main function, it seems like it deletes the whole queue, or maybe is there an affectation issue, but I can't grasp it. Here are the other function I am using (Sorry for so much code):

```
void add(int a, queue* pQ) {
   cell* new = malloc(sizeof(cell));

   (*new).content = a;
   (*new).next = NULL;

   if (empty(*pQ)){
      pQ->start = new;
   } else {
      (pQ->end)->next = new;
   }
   pQ->end = new;
}

int pop_first_cell(queue* pQ) {
   int deleted_queue_content = -1;

   if (pQ == NULL){
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   } 
   if (pQ->start != NULL) {
      cell* temp = pQ->start;
      deleted_queue_content = temp->content;
      pQ->start = temp->next;
      free(temp);
   }
   return(deleted_queue_content);
}

void deleteElement(queue* pQ, int element) {

    int contentTemp;
    queue *queueTemp = malloc(sizeof (queue));
    *queueTemp = create();

    while (contentTemp != -1) {
        contentTemp = pop_first_cell(pQ);

        if (contentTemp != element && contentTemp != -1) {
            add(contentTemp, queueTemp);
        }
    }

    *pQ = *queueTemp;
}
```

I'd really be grateful if someone could help, I know it's a lot of code, but when I don't give it fully, people usually say that some code is missing... But I'm scared that too much code would just scare you guys away ^^'

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you post the definition of `queue`?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. You are worried about the "minimal", the bigger problem is currently the "complete".

Comment: It also looks like `nodeTopologicalOrder`, alocated with `malloc` is not initialized before your first call to `add()`.

Comment: There usually are more than one valid topological sortings. Can you describe how your algorithm is supposed to operate? E.g. if two nodes could be listed first, which one do you expect?

Comment: If there are two nodes, the order doesn't matter here. I will add the queue definition.

Comment: My algorithm searches for the node with no predecessors (Empty in the predecessor list) then removes the predecessor-less-node from the other nodes' predecessor list, which in turns, might make some other node left without predecessors, and this loops until the end. Also, I've initialized the nodeTopologicalOrder, and it didn't change my issue sadly, :( but thanks nevertheless for the mention!

Comment: Please edit useful info into question instead of adding comments.